# skip null or 0 value while using row_number sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, rank, sql-server-2017, row-number

i am trying to get row_number from the data, but i want to skip the null or 0 value

```
DECLARE @ProcessId INT = 6013006
DECLARE @CommHeaderId int

SELECT  @CommHeaderId = a.id
FROM    EprocUltimate.dbo.commercial_header a 
WHERE   a.process_id = @ProcessId

SELECT  b.rank_quotation, c.rank_nego,
        CASE ISNULL(a.quotation_usd, 0) WHEN 0 THEN a.quotation_idr ELSE a.quotation_usd END As  Quotation,
        CASE ISNULL(a.nego_usd, 0) WHEN 0 THEN a.nego_idr ELSE a.nego_usd END As Nego
FROM    EprocUltimate.dbo.commercial_vendor a
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  a.id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CASE quotation_usd WHEN 0 THEN quotation_idr ELSE quotation_usd END ASC) AS rank_quotation
            FROM    EprocUltimate.dbo.commercial_vendor a
            WHERE   a.commercial_header_id = @CommHeaderId AND a.commercial_admin_bid_evaluation_result = 'Pass'
        ) b ON a.id = b.id
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  a.id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CASE ISNULL(nego_usd, 0) WHEN 0 THEN nego_idr ELSE nego_usd END ASC) AS rank_nego          
            FROM    EprocUltimate.dbo.commercial_vendor a
            WHERE   a.commercial_header_id = @CommHeaderId AND a.commercial_admin_bid_evaluation_result = 'Pass'
        ) c ON a.id = c.id
WHERE   a.commercial_header_id = @CommHeaderId AND a.commercial_admin_bid_evaluation_result = 'Pass'
ORDER BY b.rank_quotation
```

heres the result

```
rank_quotation rank_nego, value1,       value2
1                  3      775460000.00  770000000.00
2                  1      781036525.00  NULL
3                  2      786250000.00  NULL
```

from this query what i want is to get row_numbering the rank_nego with having value first

so the result that i want to achive is

```
rank_quotation rank_nego, value1,       value2
1                  1      775460000.00  770000000.00
2                  2      781036525.00  NULL
3                  3      786250000.00  NULL
```

Comment: You question contains no table schema, no sample data, and deals with non-trivial code. Please have a read through [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Your query seems way more complicated than necessary.  You might want to ask *another* question, explaining what the code is supposed to be doing and providing sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a little workaround to have your NULL values as last records in your subquery with the `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ...) as rank_nego`

```sql
(
    SELECT  a.id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 
       -- This statement will first sort records having nego_usd and nego_idr as NULL/0 at the end of the list 
       CASE WHEN ISNULL(nego_usd, 0) = 0 AND ISNULL(nego_idr, 0) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ASC,
       -- and then sort with the real values
       CASE ISNULL(nego_usd, 0) WHEN 0 THEN nego_idr ELSE nego_usd END ASC
    ) AS rank_nego
    FROM    EprocUltimate.dbo.commercial_vendor a
    WHERE   a.commercial_header_id = @CommHeaderId AND a.commercial_admin_bid_evaluation_result = 'Pass'
) c ON a.id = c.id
```